# Pandas Column Value Lookup, append

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like some help automating a task with excel data.  Below I have one excel file,  Sheet1 & Sheet2.

Sheet1 has multiple columns and one being "Old_Codes"

Sheet2 has multiple columns with one being "Old_Codes" & "New_Codes"

I am trying to see if Sheet1 "Old_Codes" value in listed in Sheet2 "Old_Codes" values.  If true, then copy Sheet2 "New_Codes" value (same row) back to Sheet1 "New_Codes" column, newly created.

I have been performing a excel text to column data with "Old_Codes" and manually filtering each column, then find and replace value where needed.  Afterewards, I have been concatenating the excel columns back together to get the results.

I have put together a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish with the follow code bit. I would really appreciate some insight to a better cleaner way of processing is possible.

Thanks

```
#----Code Below-----#
import pandas as pd

#excel sheet1 - values to look up
old_codes= ({
    'Old_Codes':["EF,JU","JU,DH,ALK","EF,ZZ","DH,EF,DH","ALK,EF,JU"],

          })

df = pd.DataFrame(old_codes)
#--------------------------------------------------------------
#excel sheet2 old data to new data conversion
old_to_new_conv= ({
    'Old_Codes':["EF","JU","DH","ALK"],
    'Description': ['Effect H','Judda M','DiH Radar','Air FreezeLK'],
    'New_Codes':['EFFE','JUDT','DIRH','FREZ'],
          })

df1 = pd.DataFrame(old_to_new_conv)
#--------------------------------------------------------------

#Results Needed
#Back on Sheet1 column next to Old_Codes columnw

results= ({
    'Old_Codes':["EF,JU","JU,DH,ALK","DH,EF,DH","ALK,EF,JU"],
    'New_Codes_Results':["EFFE,JUDT","JUDT,DIRH,FREZ","DIRH,EFFE,DIRH","FREZ,EFFE,JUDT"],
          })

df2 = pd.DataFrame(results)


#PrintArea
print('Sheet1')
print(df)
print('\n')
print('Sheet2 - Conversion')
print(df1)
print('\n')
print('Sheet1 - Results')
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to tackle such a problem is to explode the DataFrame into individual rows for each element and then merge onto them the `New_Codes` where possible

```
df_expl = df.Old_Codes.str.split(',').explode().to_frame()
df_expl = df_expl.reset_index().merge(df1[['Old_Codes','New_Codes']],how='left')
```

From here you can either drop the non-matching ones if you want a partial translation

```
df_expl = df_expl.dropna()
```

**or** remove the whole exploded group if you do not want it translated at all

```
untranslatable = df_expl.loc[df_expl.New_Codes.isna(),'index']
df_expl = df_expl.loc[~df_expl['index'].isin(untranslatable)]
```

This last one results in the ouput defined above. The explosion of columns can now be reverted by

```
df_expl = df_expl.groupby('index').New_Codes.agg(','.join)
```

And the translation merged onto the new first sheet

```
df2 = df.merge(df_expl,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Note that if non-translated columns are to be preserved this can be achieved by adding the `how='left'` parameter in the last merge.

Comment: Thanks Arnau for taking the time to try and help me.  I was not able to understand your explanation and work this answer into solve my problem......I ended up splitting out text to column and then using a dictionary of each column to change the strings.   Thanks again for answering.